# Is there any protocol documentation of non contact thermometer?

Tags: python, protocols

I working medicine project.I need when measures non contack thermometer return data.But i dont have any documentation.I used it to sniffer but some bytes come and i parced it but i didnt understand nothing because  when parcing it doesn't look like that measured
help please)

Comment: non-contact thermometer

Comment: I you need a documentation then you need the actual product name. And you should remember that any request for off-site resources (like documentation) is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: but i already googled and havent found anything